# Mavericks - Trying to install XQuartz X11 for Inkscape, "image not found"

Tags: macos, installation, x11, osx-mavericks, inkscape

So I'm trying to install Inkscape onto my Mac, which is running on Mavericks. Upon trying to open, i'm told that I need to install X11 and am forwarded to this site http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.5.  Downloaded the file, when trying to open i'm told that the image can't be found.  How can I get X11 + Inkscape running?! Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: OP isn't established in SO so unlikely to resolve this after 5 months, so this title will just clutter searches. Recommend closing.

Comment: @user3015175 Thanks for coming back and flagging the correct answer. I think a lot of new XQuartz users may find this helpful, at least until the process is more 'streamlined'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When Inkscape asks

> Where is X11?

I had to go to Applications -> Utilities -> X11

Comment: @ScottBiggs, you are most welcome! Could you flag this as the answer please? As it helped you, it would also help others. I myself came here looking for the answer and didn't find it. Had to figure it out on my own, hence my sharing it here.

Comment: Again, good work figuring out this issue!  But I can't flag your answer; only the person who made the question can do that.  And they're such a newb, it's likely that they have disappeared or simply don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you think it did not work is because the first time Inkscape opens, it takes up to a minute and a half. It just seems to sit there, doing nothing, but it will open for sure.  Once it opens, close it completely via XQuartz, then re-open it and it will open in 2-3 seconds.  Use this direct link for the latest version of XQuartz 2.7.11.

https://www.xquartz.org

Works just fine for Mavericks 10.9.5, no worries.  If not, update to OS X 10.9.5 via AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Install the X11 2.7.4 from [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/Releases). I had to restart after this install, but it worked like a charm. MATLAB took forever to open the first round, but it eventually did and now everything seems OK.

For the record, I'm running 10.9.1 on a 2009 MacbookPro. Had the same problem after I upgraded to Mavricks and could not install X11, the 2.7.5 Package.